# Angular7 production build compiles SASS styles in a wrong way

Tags: angular, sass, compilation, mixins, production-environment

I'm using [this mixin](https://github.com/NigelOToole/angled-edges) to make sloped blocks in my app's layout. It works well until I compile the app (`ng b --prod`) and upload it to AWS. Somehow it doesn't work in the same way as it did in development, instead of this:

`clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% calc(0% + 7vw), 100% 100%, 0 100%);`

I get this:

`clip-path: polygon(0 calc(0 + 7vw),100% 0,100% 100%,0 100%);`

which is an invalid value, hence the resulting blocks look very much rectangular again. While I can (and most likely will) just define my own styles for this,
I'd like to find the reason for this weird behavior.

Does anybody know how compiling SASS for dev and for prod differs in Angular and how to fix it?

Here's my [`angular.json`](https://gist.github.com/BerekHalfhand/08cd1569c46ee0b65e8633036b92a66c) in case it's relevant.

### Update

So I defined my own classes with explicit correct values and still Angular is butchering them in a compiled version.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out it is a bug in `angular-cli`, the fix was to change settings in `angular.json`:

`"extractCss": false`

With that the problem seems to go away for this particular issue, although there might be other sneaky errors that I haven't noticed yet.

One side effect I did notice is that the compiler now complains:

`WARNING in budgets, maximum exceeded for initial. Budget 2 MB was exceeded by 36.3 kB.`

But oh well, I'll have to roll with it.

[Here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8577)'s a related github issue that is closed for some reason, even though the problem is still being encountered.

**UPD**

As I suspected it is not a real fix. Sure, it works with the classes replacement I made, but trying to switch back to the mixin, I get this value:

`polygon(0 0,100% calc(0 + 7vw),100% 100%,0 100%)`

it is missing % sign here: `calc(0 + 7vw)`.

So it can be considered only a partial solution.